# Filling up RDF data from a relational database

Tags: postgresql, rdf, owl, r2rml

I am creating an ontology based on a relational database. Some classes in my ontology are correspondent to some tables in the relational database (PostgreSQL).

I already read some documents about mappings from the W3C website. Especially [this](https://www.w3.org/TR/r2rml/) one which looks to me the right approach I should follow.

This generated a couple of questions:

1. I suspect that this mapping approach will offer me just a RDF view of the database. Am I right?
2. Once I have finished this mapping, where should I execute it? I saw some mapping processors in the reference section on the documentation but all of it looks to be outdated, some with more than 5 years of inactivity.

What I really need is a way to extract data values from some tables putting in my ontology.

Comment: Ontop for example is still an ongoing OBDA project ...

Answer (score 1):

The solutions found were:

1. No, I wasn't right. They also allow filling it up the data.
2. I have decided to use Ontop plugin inside protegé, even if I am not sure about the kind of mappings they use.